# Javascript function expression reformatting with vim replace

Tags: javascript, vim, replace

Here is the reformatting I want to do :

```
// before
var name1 = function(){ /* stuff */ }
//after
function name1(){ /* stuff */ }
```

I used a vim replace command :

```
%s/var\.*\s*\(\w*\)\s*=\s*function/function \1
```

But I found it a little long for the task (matching a var, a word, a = and a function) ...

How would you do it a nicer way ?

Comment: You could shorten it marginally by putting `function` in a capture group and referring to it with `\2` in the replacement string. Otherwise, I think this is about as short as you can get; it doesn't seem terribly long (but I may be wrong -- I don't know vim well.)

Comment: You could use a macro to do this. I personally find that easier then typing the regex replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @apsillers stated you can capture `function` to so you don't have to type it out in the replacement part of the substitute command. This yields this:

```
:%s/var\.*\s*\(\w*\)\s*=\s*\(function\)/\2 \1
```

However we can do a bit better by using `\v` or very magic to reduce the number of escapes. This yields:

```
:%s/\vvar.*\s*(\w*)\s*=\s*(function)/\2 \1
```

However we still have some issues:

- Why match `.*` when a simple `\s+` will do
- `\w*` will also match an empty string which is invalid so use `\w+`

Now we have:

```
:%s/\vvar\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*(function)/\2 \1
```

As an alternative to using a substitution you may wan to use a macro or run a normal command. I prefer to use global, `:g`, and some normal commands via `:norm`:

```
:g/=\s*function/norm ^deye3dwe"0p
```

This command finds all lines that match `=\s*function` and execute a `normal` command. The normal command we run is `^deye3dwe"0p`, which can be broken down like so:

- `^` will start the the beginning of the line. If you do not care about indention remove the `^`
- `de` delete the word (`var`) and leaves the following space
- `ye` will yank or copy the variable name with the prepended space
- `3dw` will delete 3 words which will leave us with on the `f` in `function`
- Move to the end of function via `e`
- `"0p` paste the freshly yanked variable name after `function`. We must use `"0` register because the unnamed register will be clobbered by the `3dw`

For more help see:

```
:h /\v
:h /\+
:h :g
:h :norm
:h "0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also use the substitute command, but slightly differently: `:%s/var\s\+\(\w*\)\s*=\s*\(function\)/\2 \1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the slickest I could get it in a macro:

```
0diw"fdt dtfw"fP
```

Here's the explanation:

- `0` Go to the start of the line
- `diw` delete "inside" the current word (i.e. not the following <kbd>Space</kbd>, we'll need it!)
- `"fdt` into the `f` buffer (for "function" perhaps?!) delete to the next space
- `dtf` delete up to the next `f` character
- `w` jump to the next 'word' (which gets us to the open paren)
- `"fP` 'put' from the `f` buffer before the cursor

Now a quick entry in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
noremap <F4> 0diw"fdt dtfw"fP
```

and you're gold. (Or whatever shortcut key you want instead of <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

@apsillers : putting `function` in a capture group and referring to it with `\2`

```
%s/var\.*\s*\(\w*\)\s*=\s*\(function\)/\2 \1
```

@Enermis : with a macro (assuming cursor is on the `v`of `var`) :

```
dwyef(i ^[pbbd0
```